# How to Overwrite first some bytes of a file with different bytes in android

Tags: java, android

I have a problem that I want to overwrite first 2^21 bytes of a video file with another 2^21 bytes, but I don't know how to do that? Please suggest me the right solution for the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Open the file, write the bytes. What's the problem?

Comment: exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008895/

Comment: Ya I know Kerrek but When we overwrite a file all data becomes overwritten but that is not desirable I want only 2^21 bytes be overwritten.

Comment: This also has nothing much to do with Android and everything to do with Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [RandomAccessFile](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) for opening, seeking and overwriting certain parts of a file on Android.

Answer (score -2):

tried using classic java - [here take a look for input](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html), and [for output](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/OutputStream.html). Also some subclasses about that might be more useful

Comment: OutputStream (or in detail FileOutputStream) is exactly what Sanat Pandey can not use as it only allows to replace a file with a new one or append data to an existing.